# Unknown column 'u.MemberId' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core-2.0, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I have a project that is .net core 2.0. 
I have an entity below.

```
public class UsersCoupon
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CouponId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UsedDate { get; set; }
}
```

When i try to get Datas from db(mysql) i am getting this error.

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException
  HResult=0x80004005
  Message=Unknown column 'u.MemberId' in 'field list'
  Source=MySqlConnector
Inner Exception 1:
MySqlException: Unknown column 'u.MemberId' in 'field list'
```

I dont have any MemberId column in the UsersCoupons table in my db.
I am using Pomelo.EntityFramwork.Core.Mysql 2.0.0

Note: When i change the UserId column name to MemberId it is working. But i want to use UserId.How can it be?

Comment: Take a look in DbContext. It appears that the column is remapped to MemberId.

Comment: I dont have any mapping code. Just the entities with DbSet. I dont have any relationship.

Answer (score 0):

The information you provided is not enough to find the issue. Please post us a small example project, that reproduces the issue.

You can also just do a search in your whole project for `MemberId` or `Member`, to find the root of the problem, because this name has to originate from somewhere.

Of course you can also just try upgrading to `2.2.6` or `3.0.0`, because Pomelo's `2.0.0` is quite old and a lot of significant changes were implemented since then.